# How to disable resizing width of rowheader?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there any way to disable resizing of the width of a `DataGridView` rowheader, without setting `AllowUserToResizeRows` to False?

I've found `row.HeaderCell.Resizable` but it's readonly.

Comment: You want fixed height, width or both?

Comment: yes can you please tell us little more.. u talking about height or width? as far as i know header height is fixed by default, it very on the basis of font size.. bu by default width is not fixed u can drag the divider to change the width.. what exactly u want.??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [DataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158661(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the width of the row headers
>   is adjustable and whether it can be adjusted by the user or is
>   automatically adjusted to fit the contents of the headers.

```
myGrid.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.. using the below code -

```
yourDataGridView.Columns[0].Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
```

now you can not change the width of the first column in datagridview

Comment: `HeaderCell` is not in the first([0]) column. It's an extra element of a row. So it does not work. It's header with an arrow to click on for any desired operation

Comment: `column [0]` mean first column either its column of data row or header row.. I will request you to try..

Comment: Oh my god. I have already said, that I want to do it not for the data columns, but for the `HeaderCell`. It's not the same. It's the small button on the left of the row with small arrow on it.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9ykan7a4fsu6l2/DatargidView.png?dl=0)

Comment: oops I got your point.. earlier I misunderstood ur question and comment.. :P i will try, and let u know if find anything useful.